# Excel selective increment

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I'm trying to write a script in excel that returns a correlating job serial number (which resides on a different sheet) when a cell is filled with the job name.

`=IF(D5="Misc",Jobs!A2,IF(D5=1715,Jobs!A3,IF(D5=1725,Jobs!A4,IF(D5=5640,Jobs!A5,IF(D5=6121,Jobs!A7,IF(D5=6150,Jobs!A8,IF(D5="6161-IDC",Jobs!A10,IF(D5="6161-JM",Jobs!A11,IF(D5=6161,Jobs!A12,IF(D5=6535,Jobs!A14,IF(D5="Hudson",Jobs!A14,IF(D5="Berendo",Jobs!A15,IF(D5="Berendo-Move",Jobs!A16,IF(D5="Bungalos",Jobs!A17,IF(D5="Bungalo",Jobs!A17,IF(D5="Camarillo",Jobs!A18,IF(D5="Indio",Jobs!A19,IF(D5="Lillian",Jobs!A20,IF(D5="6161-Beam",Jobs!A21,IF(D5="6161-Roof",Jobs!A22))))))))))))))))))))`

The above script does what I need it to do, the problem is I need it copied to 30+ rows with ONLY the "D5" value incrementing. When I hover in the cell corner and drag down to new cells it increments other references besides the "D5" value.

I did a search and replace and manually copied the script to each of the 30 cells to get it functional for now but I'm going to have to do that every time I add a job. I'd like to just add the new job condition and use the fill handle to drag it to all cells, I feel like I need an escape character though to limit what cells are being incremented, I'm just not sure what that would be (it's always going to be column "D", I just need the row incremented to "d6, d7," etc)- thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you not use a `VLOOKUP()` instead?

Comment: Do you know about absolute references? $A$1, $A1, A$1 are examples for completely absolute references, column absolute and row absolute references respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a case sensitive replacement of `A$` for `A` may be adequate:

```
=IF(D5="Misc",Jobs!A$2,IF(D5=1715,Jobs!A$3,IF(D5=1725,Jobs!A$4,IF(D5=5640,Jobs!A$5,IF(D5=6121,Jobs!A$7,IF(D5=6150,Jobs!A$8,IF(D5="6161-IDC",Jobs!A$10,IF(D5="6161-JM",Jobs!A$11,IF(D5=6161,Jobs!A$12,IF(D5=6535,Jobs!A$14,IF(D5="Hudson",Jobs!A$14,IF(D5="Berendo",Jobs!A$15,IF(D5="Berendo-Move",Jobs!A$16,IF(D5="Bungalos",Jobs!A$17,IF(D5="Bungalo",Jobs!A$17,IF(D5="Camarillo",Jobs!A$18,IF(D5="Indio",Jobs!A$19,IF(D5="Lillian",Jobs!A$20,IF(D5="6161-Beam",Jobs!A$21,IF(D5="6161-Roof",Jobs!A$22))))))))))))))))))))
```